# what's the difference from between these two way to create property in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface DZActionView(){
    NSString* _name;
}

@interface DZActionView()
  @property(strong, nonatomic)NSString* name;
@end
```

What's the difference?
I only know that if I use @property; it generates getter/setter methods and a _name property.

Comment: The first isn't a property, it is just an instance variable.  The second is a property.

Comment: late to say. but thx bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean for this:

```
@interface DZActionView(){
    NSString* _name;
}
```

to be your first way of creating a property, and

```
@interface DZActionView()
    @property(strong, nonatomic)NSString* name;
@end
```

to be your second way, then you're misunderstanding how Objective-C uses properties.

The first method is not a property, it's an instance variable only. It can't be accessed by other objects.

The second way does in fact create a property. In earlier versions of Objective-C, you would need to create a backing instance variable for the property. Which is what the `_name` variable you've included is for. This is mostly done for you automatically now unless you do something that requires it to be added explicitly.

If you include your own `getter` and `setter` methods (similar these):

```
- (NSString*)name {
    return _name;
}
- (void)setName:(NSString*)name {
    _name = name
}
```

Then these are explicitly referring to the `_name` instance variable you've mentioned, and are using it as the backing variable.

Comment: late to say. but thx bro.